# Display Email list of my FB friends

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing functionality for Listing email(those who shared) of my-friends(who ever is logged in) from FaceBook. Is it possible to do with Graph API ? I tried for login and then allowing permission for my App. Without any change it sometimes works and stops. I don't know why? Also how can i get list of friend's email...?

Comment: Working example is also accepted to list friend's email...

Comment: some where i found that we cant get email as its not permitted. is it true.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't provide friend's email id through API.

Check Permissions of API it is not [allowed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook APIs don’t expose email addresses of friends.

You can only get the logged-in user email with the explicitly permission email.
All permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Workaround through Yahoo Contacts:
http://www.labnol.org/internet/export-email-addresses-from-facebook/12970/